# Majorization for vector valued function: looking for literature

Tags: order-theory, majorization

Let $x,y\in R^{d}$. A function $f:R^{d}\to R$ is called Schur convex if 
$$
x\prec y\;\;\rightarrow\;\;f(x)\leq f(y).
$$

I am interested in functions $g:R^{d}\to R^{d}$ such that

$$
x\prec y\;\;\rightarrow\;\;g(x)\prec g(y).
$$

Does these functions have a name? Any literature suggested? Thank you. Fabio

Comment: What is $x\prec y$?

Comment: Hi, is the majorization order.